# Add timer intervar for show / hide message Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have javascript function that show alert message and after 2 sec hide it. here is full function above

```
function hideNotifyReport(noanimation)
{
    var el          = jQuery('#report-notify');

    var interval    = 2; // sec 

    if (noanimation)
    {
        el.hide();
        sizeNotifyReport();
    }
    else
    {   
        el.css('opacity', 1).animate({ opacity: 0 }, interval*2000, function()
        {
            hideNotifyReport(true);
        });
    }
}
```

my problem is with this line :

```
el.css('opacity', 1).animate({ opacity: 0 }, interval*2000, function()
```

I want to add interval to opacity 1 to that message will be shown by "n" time and after hide. Problem is that now it shows and too fast hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I think this is what you want:](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

```
el.css('opacity', 1).delay(interval*1000).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1000, function(){...
```